# Passed data value will stay on page after submitting form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a 2 pages and I want to stay the data value that i passed from page1.php

```
page1.php
  <form action='page2.php' method='POST' class='form-inline'>
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-info' value='Manage Child' 
  name='manage'>;
  <input type='hidden' value='<?php echo $id;?>' name='id'>
  </form>

page2.php
$id = $_POST['id'];
if(isset($_POST['passinfo'])){
$studentid=$_POST['studid'];
}else{
$studentid='';
}
<form>
<input type='hidden' name='parentid' value='<?php echo $id;?>'
<input type='hidden' name='studentid' value='<?php echo $studentid;?>'
<input type='text' name='studentname'>
</form>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name=studid value='<?php echo $stud_id?'>
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Assign' name='passinfo'>
</form>
```

my problem is if I click the 'passinfo' button and submit the 'studid' value the '$parentid' value will be unindentified variable. My question is how do I maintain the value of the '$parentid' even if I submit a form

Comment: `<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'>` this one seems wrong to me. Isn't it supposed to be `<?php echo $id ?>` or something like that?

Comment: Yes it is. I edited it thanks for pointing out

Comment: The hidden elements (and all form elements) will only apply to the form tag that they fall under. There isn't a way to say that these elements apply to multiple other forms without just copying the elements under each form tag.

Answer (score 0):

You must place hidden inputs in one form:

```html
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type="hidden" name="parentid" value='<?=$id?>'>
<input type="hidden" name="studentid" value='<?=$studentid?>'>
<input type='hidden' name=studid value='<?=$stud_id?'>
<input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' value='Assign' name='passinfo'>
</form>
```